# Making a custom stitch z brush

Tags: modeling, uv, sculpting, uv-image-editor

I watched a video of blender guru on adding stitching to a couch.  He added a 2nd uv and overlaid a zbrush in the bump map and manually aligning the uv to match.  Is there a way I can make a texture paint brush to paint a bump map on a stitch to easily add stitching.  If so how do I do it and how do I create a texture of all the maps and UVs to import to unity.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit tedious to paint a b&w stitch directly in Blender but you can:

- Create a stitch on a flat plane:

[image]

- Choose the top view, in *Solid* mode, in the *Viewport Shading* panel, choose *Matcap* and choose the normal matcap:

[image]

- In the *View* menu, choose *Viewport Render Image*:

[image]

- In an image editor, only keep the normal map image:

[image]

- Unwrap your object and use the image in an *Image Texture* plugged into a *Normal* map in order to create your stitch:

[image]
[image]

Comment: could I plug the image into a custom texture paint brush? will it only affect the normals?

Comment: how exactly would I do that? I tried to that but I messed somethin up.

Comment: and whats the difference between a normal map and height? they look like they do the same thing

Comment: oops yes sorry it's not possible to bake the height map, so baking the normals, or using the method I explain, are the most convenient thing to do. Not big difference between normal and height map in the result, the method is different: normals check the face normal orientations, height check the heights